# publish app on xcode without specific iOS devices

Tags: xcode

How to deploy my app to an ipa file and install it on iOS devices without select a specific device. I do not know these devices.

Example: I will project graduation project and I will send it to the programming department to try the application

On developer.apple site there are add devices?

I have an account on developer.apple.com

Comment: I don't think you can do that . You have to specify which device you are targeting for such as 10.3 . What I understand is you can try TestFlight.

Comment: I don't mean version like 10.3 , 11 or last version of iOS 11.3 >> I mean when I don't know the UDID such as "Name your device and enter its Unique Device Identifier (UDID).
"